# Eclipse WTP + Gradle Buildship not deploying all project dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, gradle, buildship

Config: Eclipse Neon.1.  BuildShip plugin 1.0.21. Gradle 3.2. Tomcat 8.0.33.

Project Structure:

- CmbProduct

  - Common
  - CommonServer
  - Model
  - CaBridge
  - WebApp

I've got a Web Services application project ("WebApp") which is dependent on multiple other projects.  When I use Eclipse WST/WTP to deploy and run WebApp via Tomcat, only Model.jar from "Model" is deployed into the tomcat WST runtime directory as:

> .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapp/WEB-INF/lib/Model.jar

All other dependencies for hibernate, etc do seem to be deployed correctly to the same dir above.

This broke when I changed eclipse to use Buildship.  Previously I used the Eclipse STS (Spring) plugin and that worked fine.

Here is the web project (WebApp) build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'

dependencies {
    compile project(":Common")
    compile project(":Model")
    compile project(":CommonServer")
    compile project(":CaBridge")
    ...
}

eclipse {
    wtp {
        component {
            // Configure the <Context path="..."/> in server.xml
            contextPath = '/console'

            // dependencies to mark as deployable with lib folder deploy path
            libConfigurations += [ project(":MagniCompCommon").configurations.runtime ]
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example I first tried without the eclipse.wtp.libConfigurations section.  I tried adding that to fix the problem but it has no effect.  Yes, I did run 'gradle eclipseWtp', then Add/Remove the 'WebApp' application from its server entry after making that change.

If I go to Eclipse -> WebApp -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries and look at "Web App Libraries" I see "Model" but not the other projects.  If I look at "Project and External Dependencies" I see all projects listed.

Here is the build.gradle for Model (working):

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'

dependencies {
    compile project(":MagniCompCommon")
}
```

Here is build.gradle for Common (not deployed):

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'

dependencies {
    //compile project(":MagniCompCommon")
    compile project(":Model")

    compile("org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:$jerseyGlassfishVersion")
    // Required for JAX-RS Client
    compile("org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:$jerseyGlassfishVersion")
}
```

Here is build.gradle for the top level project (CmbProject):

```
apply plugin: 'java'

subprojects {

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'nebula.provided-base'
    apply plugin: 'nebula.optional-base'

    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    javadoc.enabled = false

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                // Define all source dirs - Purpose is to add "src-gen"
                srcDirs = ["src/main/java", "src-gen"]
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Repositories used by each subproject must be given below.
     * Because each subproject resolves dependencies of other
     * subprojects, all subprojects must know all repos.
     * In other words, if projectA needs repo "foo.org" and projectB
     * depends upon projectA, then projectB needs repo "foo.org" as
     * well.
     */
    repositories {
        maven {
            // Local repo for annovention
            url uri("$rootDir/MagniCompCommon/repo")
        }

        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "http://download.java.net/maven/2"
        }
        maven {
            // Texo/EMF
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/org/eclipse/emf"
        }
        maven {
            // Eclipse
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/public/eclipse"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss"
        }
        maven {
            url "http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons"
        }
        maven {
            url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots"
        }
        maven {
            url("http://maven.clapper.org")
        }
        /*
         * -ADD LAST- so that it doesn' override any others
         * DynamicReports depends upon JasperReports which lists their own
         * bug fixed versions of packages like "com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7.js2"
         * This repo provides such patched packages.
         */
        maven {
            url("http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2")
        }
    }

    /*
     * Variables local to this file
     */
    def bouncycastleVersion = "1.54" // Was 1.51
    def slf4jVersion = "1.7.19"
    def hibernateVersion = "4.3.11.Final"
    def texoVersion = "0.9.0-v201501182340"
    def emfVersion = "2.11.0-v20150123-0347"
    def jnaVersion = "4.1.0"

    ext {
        /*
         * Variables here are used by subprojects
         */
        vaadinVersion = "7.6.8" // was 7.6.4
        vaadinIconsVersion = "1.0.1"
        jerseyGlassfishVersion = "2.23.2" // was 2.22.2
    }

    dependencies {

        /*
         * PRODUCT SPECIFIC
         */
        compile("org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:$bouncycastleVersion")
        compile("org.bouncycastle:bcprov-ext-jdk15on:$bouncycastleVersion")
        compile("org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:$bouncycastleVersion")

        compile("com.h2database:h2:1.3.176")

        testCompile("org.testng:testng:6.9.4")

        /*
         * MagniComp common and product
         */
        compile("org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.6.9")
        // Logging slf4j API
        compile("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:$slf4jVersion")
        // Send JCL to slf4j
        compile("org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:$slf4jVersion")
        // Anything using JUL should defer to slf4j
        compile("org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:$slf4jVersion")
        // Send slf4j to log4j 1.2 for those JARs which use slf4j
        compile("org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:$slf4jVersion")
        // Log4j itself
        compile("log4j:log4j:1.2.17")
        // Hibernate
        // Do not include "hibernate-core" explicitly as hibernate-entitymanager will take care of it
        compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:$hibernateVersion")
        compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:$hibernateVersion")

        compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.38")

        // Texo
        compile("org.eclipse.emf:org.eclipse.emf.texo:$texoVersion")
        compile("org.eclipse.emf:org.eclipse.emf.texo.server:$texoVersion")
        compile("org.eclipse.emf:org.eclipse.emf.texo.xml:$texoVersion")
        // Texo dependencies (not automaticly added by texo)
        compile("org.eclipse.emf:org.eclipse.emf.common:$emfVersion")
        compile("org.eclipse.emf:org.eclipse.emf.ecore:$emfVersion")
        compile("org.eclipse.emf:org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi:$emfVersion")
        // Required by org.eclipse.emf
        // Disable because it's causing: 
        //   java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.osgi.framework.BundleReference"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
        //compile("org.eclipse.core:org.eclipse.core.runtime:3.7.0")

        compile("org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.2")

        // Apache HTTP client
        compile("org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5")
        // EventBus and more
        compile("com.google.guava:guava:18.0")

        // Quartz scheduler
        compile("org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.2.2") {
            exclude group: "c3p0", module: "c3p0"
        }
        // Java Mail
        compile("javax.mail:mail:1.4.5")

        // JNA for Common and CaBridge
        compile("net.java.dev.jna:jna:$jnaVersion")
        compile("net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:$jnaVersion")

        // This package provided by Tomcat or Servlet container
        provided("javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0")

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to some help from the gradle forum I found the solution.

Each project which is a dependency of a WTP project must each have:

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
```

Having this only in the WTP project is not enough.